# My Phone Stuck in boot screen How to recover?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot

I am using micromax canvas hd A116.  I tried to install Custom ROM and I installed safely.  After 1 Week I tried to reset my phone using factory reset under settings.  After that my phone is not starting.

1. The problem is my volume up button is not working due to that I cant go to recovery mode.
2. In adb and fastboot my phone is not detecting (This is because USB debugging is not enabled in Developer settings, not sure)

Is there any to recover my phone using adb or any other method ?

**UPDATE**

Now my phone got detected, I installed the Driver . But right now I am getting this error.

How to resolve this error ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried formatting the device using SPFlash tool. If not , do so.
If you have followed usual safety rules for flashing you should have your original ROM backups through nandroid. Re-flash them after successfully partitioning the device.
The usual procedure is to flash recovery.take nandroid backup, flash your choice of rom.
For now please keep device charged to max and keep multiple recoveries and firmware images (not roms) in your internal and sdcard. Please install the firmware immediately after formatting the device without any reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can neither boot the phone nor access recovery or bootloader, you can try the following
1. Download latest [SP Flash tool](http://www.mediafire.com/download/xsk5dnvbk8z8c45/SP-Flash-Tool-v5.1528.00.zip).

2. Download this stock ROM: [S9201_4.2_MP_F3F8_B1_IN_MMX_13_FLASHER_USER.zip](http://d-h.st/IOJ)
3. Extract it, open flash_tool.exe and load the scatter file
4. Now connect your phone and flash by clicking 'Download'.

Source: [[Upd Stock ROM] [MMX A116] [Baseband Ver:MOLY.WR8.W1248.MD.WG.MP.V6.P18]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2426034)

Comment: I tired your method , but it's not detecting my phone. Check update part in my Question.

Comment: My phone got detected , But I am getting this error "pmt changed for the rom it must be downloaded"  How to resolve this ?

Comment: [How-To: Fix Sp Flash Tool PMT change Rom Error](http://www.nextclock.com/2015/02/how-to-fix-sp-flash-tool-pmt-change-rom.html)

Comment: (late, but whatever) When a device is booting, it isn't accessible from ADB. Thus you can't push anything to it